# A 27GB Table Population causes the TLOG to grow to 211GB

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

my brain is fried.

I work in an organisation where every night we pull data from the source system into a staging area, then into production and because of this we have out DB's set to Simple Recovery Mode.

I have one particular table with around 200 million records equating to about 27GB, when the production table gets populated from either staging or a Temp Table the TLOG grows to 211GB.

- This happens with and without Indexes/Constraints on the table
- I am using INSERT INTO tableA SELECT * FROM tableB
- It is the only thing running at the time of my population testing

It also "overgrows" to 90 GB when using a different DB to test the population of a replica table.

However the 20GB TempDB TLOG when populating a Temp Table, and I am assuming that TempDB does something different with TLOGs?

I am not overly savvy with the background workings of TLOG but I wouldn't have expected this to happen.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What you described by itself shouldn't cause that much growth in the Transaction Log normally. What are the Auto-Growth settings set to for that database? (You can find it in the "Database Properties" under "Files".)

Comment: I have set the starting size to 128GB and incremental growth of 1GB.

When I ran the test yesterday evening the TLOG was empty when I started, and by the time the table had been populated was up to 211GB.

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server? What transaction isolation level are you using? Is Accelerated Database Recovery (ADR) enabled?

Comment: I am using Enterprise Edition, version 15.0.4326.1.  My Isolation Level is set to read committed and I don't have ADR enabled.
The DB current compatibility level is 110, there was an upgrade to 2019 recently and I haven't had the time to run through changing the CL on some DB's
This problem did exist before the upgrade however.

Comment: Perhaps the whole thing is being run under a single transaction, and you are importing or copying the data (or rebuilding indexes) mulltiple times?